# Erro ao buildar um projeto no React-Native

Tags: react-native

Boa noite, estou com o seguinte erro ao buildar com o react-native (imagem).

Estou usando windows 7, gerei o projeto usando react-native init dacerto --version 0.55.4

depois fui na pasta do projeto e rodei react-native run-android. E não consigo rodá-lo. Estou buildando dele direto no celular pois o android studio é muito pesado e já fiz um projeto de forma semelhante e deu certo.
Alguém pode me ajudar, por favor?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Dei uma sacada na sua dúvida e existe uma pergunta similar dela no StackOverflow em Inglês. Este é o [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41267005/failed-to-crunch-file-android-studio-appmergedebugresources).

Resumindo e meio que traduzindo, a PATH do seu projeto na hora de executar certas tasks, ficaram grandes demais para o processamento.

Ex:

- C:\Asdasdasd\asdasdasd\asdasdasd\asdasdassdz\< Projeto >\< Toneladas de Subfolders >

Tente alterar para algo do tipo:

- C:\Workspace\< Projeto > ou C:\< Projeto >

Isso, segundo a [resposta da comunidade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41267005/failed-to-crunch-file-android-studio-appmergedebugresources#answer-41314222), é resolutivo para seu problema.